# I am having problems in Python 2.7.5 to get EasyGUI working on Mac OS X

Tags: python, macos, osx-yosemite, easygui

I am running Mac OS X Yosemite (v10.10) and I cannot get EasyGUI to work. I tried looking on easygui.sourceforge.net, but I got no working results. I was able to get it running temporarily if I typed in the following:
from distutils.core import setup
setup(
    name='easygui',
    version='0.96',
    py_modules=['easygui'],
    )
I am guessing that I installed it in the wrong place. As it said, I installed it in the same place as IDLE (not sure of the exact location), but it did nothing. I only got an error message. Any help?

Comment: Readers do not have your screen in front of them, so please state the error message you're getting.

Comment: a quick fix might be to transfer the easygui files into your site_packages folder and then try to import again

Answer (score 1):

When you install new packages use always pip install to achieve that. It will install it in the right place so you can just import it in your pythons scripts. Just do pip install easygui, you can find the pacakage here https://pypi.python.org/pypi/easygui

If you need to install pip just type sudo easy_install pip and your done.